# Multiple categories one page with Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

Is there a way to get multiple category pots on a one page website that's going to be built with Jekyll?

Ive tried searching around but there doesn't seem to be an answer anywhere?

In the code I have tried messing about with the following, in one section:

```
            <section>

                <div class="gallery">

                    <h2>Gallery</h2>
                    {% for gallery in site.categories %}

                    {% for catposts in gallery %}
                    {% for catposts in catposts %}
                    <div>
                        <img src="assets/images/gallery/{{ catposts.img }}" alt="">
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}

                    {% endfor %}
                </div>

            </section>
```

and in the other:

```
        <section>
            <div class="news">

            <h2>News</h2>

                <!-- Page Content -->
                {% for post in site.posts reversed %}
                {% capture thecycle %}{% cycle 'odd', 'even' %}{% endcapture %}
                {% if thecycle == 'odd' %}

                <div>
                    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
                    {{ post.content }}
                </div>

                {% else %}

                <div>
                    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
                    {{ post.content }}
                </div>

                {% else %}

                <div>
                    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
                    {{ post.content }}
                </div>

                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}

            </div>
        </section>
```

in the gallery section there are about eight gallery posts even though I have only made one and all  of them have: `<img src="assets/images/gallery/` but no post image.

The News section posts turn up fine but the also show the gallery posts.

In the _posts folder I have:

```
_posts
-- Gallery
-- News
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a pair of lines that read:

```
{% for catposts in gallery %}
{% for catposts in catposts %}
```

What does this mean? Are there `catposts` in `catposts`?

As for the post image not showing up, that's a result of the earlier problem. Liquid can't find `catposts.img`, so it's putting a blank there, resulting in what you see. So all we need to really fix is the first problem.

## Solution from scratch

Assuming you want the following structure:

```
site.categories = {
                   galleryA : {
                                subGallery1: ...,
                                subGallery2: ...,
                              },
                   galleryB : { ... },
                   ...
                  }
```

To create [collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/), you need in your `config.yml`:

```
collections:
  galleryA:
    output: true
    permalink: /galleryA/:path/
  galleryB:
    output: true
    permalink: /galleryB/:path/
  ...
```

Then in your source root folder create the following directory structure:

```
_galleryA
    |
    subGallery1
        |
        a1-first.html
        a1-second.html
    |
    subGallery2
        |
        a2-first.html
        a2-second.html
_galleryB
    |
    ...
```

Your `_site` generated should reflect this structure. For example: `/galleryA/subGallery1/a1-first/(index.html)` is generated from `a1-first.html`. I'm assuming you know how to write the individual articles.

Comment: Tell the truth I'm completely new to Jekyll and I'm not sure what catposts means, I was following a theme from somewhere else. 

yes the structure you have there is what I am after. I have a gallery that is split into different gallery subtypes. Would I put what you have there into the top of the gallery section?